# SQLAlchemy typing support on filter for imperatively mapped attrs classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy, python-attrs

For my application I am trying to separate my "domain layer" classes from the database backend, in order to be able to unit test these classes independently of the database. I use mypy for static analysis and I get typing errors when using `Query.filter()` with the attributes of my imperatively mapped class. I don't want to use `# type: ignore` everywhere I use `Query.filter()` so I am looking for a correct solution to this problem.

I created the following model:

```
# project/models/user.py


from attrs import define, field


@define(slots=False, kw_only=True)
class User:
    id: int = field(init=False)
    username: str = field()
    hashed_password: str = field()
    is_active: bool = field(default=True)
    is_superuser: bool = field(default=False)
```

In production I of course use the database with the following table:

```
# project/db/tables/user.py

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression

from ..base import mapper_registry


user = sa.Table(
    "users",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("username", sa.String(155), unique=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column("hashed_password", sa.String(200), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("is_active", sa.Boolean, nullable=False, server_default=expression.true()),
    sa.Column(
        "is_superuser", sa.Boolean, nullable=False, server_default=expression.false()
    ),
)
```

And to map my class to the table I did the following:

```
# project/db/__init__.py

from .base import mapper_registry
from .tables import user

from project.models import User


mapper_registry.map_imperatively(User, user)
```

The functionality works as expected, correct queries are being constructed, however when I try to call `Query.filter()` with the attributes of my model class, I get typing errors from mypy, because `Query.filter()` expects column expressions and not plain python types (I use mypy bundled with sqlalchemy `sqlalchemy = {version = "^2.0.15", extras = ["mypy"]}` and I included the mypy plugin in mypy.ini)

```
# project/queries.py

from typing import List

from sqlalchemy import true
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from project.models import User


def list_active(session: Session) -> List[User]:
    return session.query(User).filter(User.is_active == true()).all()
```

And the error:

```
project/queries.py12: error: Argument 1 to "filter" of "Query" has incompatible type "bool"; expected "Union[ColumnElement[bool], _HasClauseElement, SQLCoreOperations[bool], ExpressionElementRole[bool], Callable[[], ColumnElement[bool]], LambdaElement]"  [arg-type]
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** No "correct" solution, in my opinion, because it is not referred in the documentation.

`session.query(User).filter(users_table.columns["is_active"].is_(True)).all()`

Also, I do not think the imperative mapping plays a role either, the story would be the same with declarative mapping (I use this style in my projects and have seen the same problems).

Explanation:

**SQLAlchemy** does not cater for this type check of **mypy** and there is no clean workaround as far as I know. Here is a piece of code to highlight some thoughts and an "alternative", though:

```
from typing import List
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, registry
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import BinaryExpression
from attrs import define, field

from sqlalchemy.sql import expression

engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///test.sqlite3")
mapper_registry = registry()


# Data model and table objects
@define(slots=False, kw_only=True)
class User:
    id: int = field(init=False)
    username: str = field()
    hashed_password: str = field()
    is_active: bool = field(default=True)
    is_superuser: bool = field(default=False)


user = sa.Table(
    "users",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("username", sa.String(155), unique=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column("hashed_password", sa.String(200), nullable=False),
    sa.Column(
        "is_active", sa.Boolean, nullable=False, server_default=expression.true()
    ),
    sa.Column(
        "is_superuser", sa.Boolean, nullable=False, server_default=expression.false()
    ),
)


# Map the User class to the 'users' table imperatively
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(User, user)


# Function to populate the database with initial data
def populate_database():
    # 'users' table creation
    user.create(engine)

    with Session(engine) as session:
        user_1 = User(username="John Doe", hashed_password="aaa")
        user_2 = User(username="Jane Smith", hashed_password="bbb")
        user_3 = User(username="Bob Johnson", hashed_password="ccc")

        session.add(user_1)
        session.add(user_2)
        session.add(user_3)
        session.commit()


def list_active() -> List[User]:
    with Session(engine) as session:
        expr: bool = User.is_active == sa.true()
        result = session.query(User).filter(expr).all()
    return result


def list_active_with_idiom() -> List[User]:
    with Session(engine) as session:
        expr: BinaryExpression = User.is_active.is_(True)
        result = session.query(User).filter(expr).all()
    return result


def list_active_with_types() -> List[User]:
    with Session(engine) as session:
        expr: BinaryExpression = user.columns["is_active"].is_(True)
        result = session.query(User).filter(user.columns["is_active"].is_(True)).all()
    return result


# Run this once only, to populate the table with initial data using the models
# populate_database()

# Run after populating the database
print(list_active())  # question way
print(list_active_with_idiom())  # SQLAlchemy recommended way
print(list_active_with_types())  # type checking sound
```

The snippet uses the original data models and Table object of your example, just put together in the same file to allow reproducing the results. After initialising the SQLite DB by calling `populate_database()` you can run the 3 alternative functions to list the active users. `list_active()` is your original function, `list_active_with_idiom()` is the one that uses SQLAlchemy's recommended way and the last one is the type-checking sound one.

- `list_active()` evaluates the Python expression and creates a `bool` object that is fed into the `filter()` function, which is only annotated for `_ColumnExpressionArgument[bool]` (the [type](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/_typing.py#L173) that shows in the **mypy** error message). This is the original one.
- `list_active_with_idiom()` uses the **SQLalchemy** way, shown in the docs. It creates what is called a [`BinaryExpression`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.BinaryExpression) (you can see it imported for typing and explanation purposes) out of a `Column` object, the `True` keyword and the `is_()` operator. These are, respectively, the `left`, `right` and `operator` attributes of the `BinaryExpression`. The base class of this class is `OperatorExpression`, which has [`ColumnElement`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py#L2891) as base class (making the type checking pass). You can notice, though, that the line will still generate a type checking problem as it relies on the `is_()` operator creating this `BinaryExpression` out of the data model attribute (which is a boolean). `User.is_active.is_(True)` works because of the mapping between the data models and the tables, but `User.is_active` is still just a boolean to **mypy**.
- `list_active_with_types()` is the "type checking sound" version, and leverages what you can learn from the behaviour in the second option. `users_table.columns["is_active"].is_(True)` first grabs the Column object from the original `Table` object directly and then applies the same operator to compare to `True`. I am not sure this is how it is supposed to work, but makes `mypy` happy.

If you run this example, you should see the 2 following **mypy** errors:

```
main.py:61: error: Argument 1 to "filter" of "Query" has incompatible type "bool"; expected "Union[ColumnElement[bool], _HasClauseElement, SQLCoreOperations[bool], ExpressionElementRole[bool], Callable[[], ColumnElement[bool]], LambdaElement]"  [arg-type]
main.py:67: error: "bool" has no attribute "is_"  [attr-defined]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

As you can see, no type checking error for the last option. Not sure this is quite right, but I have not found it anywhere in official documentation and I see it more as a workaround to SQLAlchemy's annotations.

**Bonus comment:** Projects like **SQLModel** use **SQLAlchemy** for the ORM part; among other things this project adds a good bit of annotations. Having a read of the source it looks like they skip the **mypy** type checking for some tricky lines like this [one](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/blob/main/sqlmodel/sql/expression.py#L225).